# Inline form label align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```css
.select-trigger,
.select-trigger:focus {
  min-height: 34px;
  line-height: 2.45;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.select-trigger {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* added rule */

.form-inline .select {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Label 1</label>
      <div class="select">
        <div class="select-trigger">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Label 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Label 3</label>
      <div class="select">
        <div class="select-trigger">
          Foo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

(maybe Label 2 won't be appear in one line, if the view port is not big enough, so here is a JsBin to see it in full screen: 
http://jsbin.com/sobupicire/3/edit?output)

- **Label 1** is the problem: Label sits at the bottom of the div. It should be in vertical middle of `div.select`
- **Label 2** is the desired look
- **Label 3** is the same as Label 1, but with some text it looks like it should (the label is in vertical middle of `div.select`

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: Since you are applying different css classes to Label 1,2,3 it is wonder they look different ... If you want them to look like `Label 2`, just apply the css class from `Label 2` to all of them. Otherwist you should edit your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @TomB. Label 1 is the problem. The label is at the bottom of the div. It should be in the vertical middle, like at Label 2 and Label 3. Make sure you watch it in jsbin too: http://jsbin.com/sobupicire/3/edit?output

Comment: @printxdiv0 It wont help, because Label 2 has different html markup. It is just an example how Label 1 should look like.

Comment: if you  tipe sometinhg in the first  <div class="select-trigger">ff</div> it will be ok strange ...

Comment: @I-amSam exactly. I don't know how could I achieve the same effect by css, leaving it without text.

Comment: you can do  <div class="select-trigger"> &nbsp</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "label-control" for all label and "form-control"

http://jsbin.com/calaconidu/1/edit?output

Comment: actually adding ´vertical-align: middle;´ was enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one input is a select-trigger and the other is a select trigger with content, while the other is an inputbox. Try and keep them consistent and that will solve your problem

Comment: please read my post again: Label 2 is just a visual demonstration how it should look like. Label 3 is just pointing out, that with some content it would look alright. And the problem is still Label 1, which should look like (withtout any content) like Label 2 and Label 3.